# How to filter and sum the array of integers in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a task that requires to sum ALL `topup_val` performed by the `id_user` that had at least one `topup_val` ever by the amount of €15 exactly. This task needs to be solved in a single `SELECT` statement, without any window functions or subqueries (nested `SELECT`). I'm still a beginner in SQL so I found it struggle to finish this task.

I converted the `topup_val` rows for each `id_user` to array using `array_agg()`. However, I cannot filter the array using `WHERE` clause because `WHERE` clause is performed before the aggregate function.

Thank you so much!

**Table `topups`**

```
 id_user | topup_val
---------+-----------
    1    |    10
    1    |    15
    1    |    5
    2    |    10
    2    |    10
    3    |    15
    3    |    15
    3    |    10
```

**Converted to array**

```
 id_user | topup_array
---------+------------------
    1    |     {10, 15, 5}
    2    |        {10, 10}
    3    |    {15, 15, 10}
```

**Expected result**

```
 id_user | topup_sum
---------+------------
    1    |     30
    3    |     40
```

**My PostgreSQL queries**

```
SELECT id_user, array_agg(topup_val) AS array_topup
    FROM topups 
    WHERE 15 = ANY(array_topup)
    GROUP BY id_user
    ORDER BY id_user;
```

Comment: You can filter on aggregates using the `HAVING` clause. Add one like `HAVING 15 = array_agg(topup_val)` (aliases can't be referenced in the `HAVING` clause). You can also simply use `SUM(topup_val)` in the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between group by and order by you can further filter your result set with `HAVING`:

```
SELECT id_user,sum(topup_val)
FROM topups 
GROUP BY id_user
HAVING array_agg(topup_val) && array[15]
ORDER BY id_user;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2d8b5c93650aa2c40ebf116c6193e091)

```
WITH topups (id_user,topup_val) AS ( VALUES
(1,10),(1,15),(1,5),(2,10),(2,10),(3,15),(3,15),(3,10)) 
SELECT id_user, sum(topup_val)
FROM topups 
GROUP BY id_user
HAVING array_agg(topup_val) && array[15]
ORDER BY id_user;

 id_user | sum 
---------+-----
       1 |  30
       3 |  40
(2 rows)
```

Comment: That's great! I didn't know that I could use the aggregate functions inside HAVING clause, and also array[15] to search for `15` value in the array. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Use `HAVING` rather than `WHERE`. I appears after the `GROUP BY` clause and is calculated after aggregation, so it can be used to filter rows after aggregation.